# how to map an array to another array with different values (angularJs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Currently I am trying to use an existing array to map it to another array in order to match what the server wants.

for example...

I have an array:

```
$scope.users = [{
        "firstName": "john",
        "middleName": null,
        "lastName": "doe",
        "registrationNumber": "334"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "paul",
        "middleName": null,
        "lastName": "dean",
        "registrationNumber": "223"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "andrew",
        "middleName": null,
        "lastName": "mac",
        "registrationNumber": "132"
    }
]
```

however I want it to look like this...

```
[{
    name: "john doe",
    value: {
        registration: 334,
        last: "doe",
        first: "john"
    }
}]
```

So what I've been doing is something like this to map it out...but it only gets the first one.

```
var list = [{
    name: $scope.users[0].firstName + ' ' + $scope.users[0].lastName,
    value: {
        registration: $scope.users[0].registrationNumber,
        first: $scope.users[0].firstName,
        last: $scope.users[0].lastName
    }
}];
```

I tried to use `angular.forEach` to get all the list and push it...but hasn't really worked too well yet... any help would be great!

Comment: ever heard of Array.map?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution could be:

```
var list = $scope.users.map(function(user) {
    return {
        name: user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName,
        value: {
            registration: user.registrationNumber,
            first: user.firstName,
            last: user.lastName
        }
    };
});
```

### Explanation

[Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) iterates over the existing array and returns a new modified one.

So you have to use `map` on `$scope.users` and for each `user` you want to return a new object. In each iteration you have access on each `user`. The new objects will be stored inside `list` which will be an array.

Comment: And support for Array.map has been around for years now (watch out for < IE10) http://caniuse.com/#search=map

Comment: Is it possible to use .map without creating a new array?